# Adding a list to an object with .append

Tags: jquery

This is more of a question about how `.append` works

I have a div which I'd like to attach a ul list to

At first i tried doing

```
myDiv.append("<ul>");
myDiv.append("<li>....</li>");
myDiv.append("</ul>");
```

but this seems to create a ul on the first line and then closes it before the next append.
So i ended up adding all the lines to a string and then appending the string in one append call.

Why couldn't it be done the first way? Is there a way to do that or doing it the second way i mentioned better?

thanks

Comment: "*Why couldn't it be done the first way?*" Because `.append()` is a DOM manipulation and the DOM doesn't support including partial elements. It essentially "*fixes*" the `"<ul>"` to `<ul></ul>` immediately so the resulting element tree remains valid.

Answer (score 0):

DOM interactions have VERY BAD performance. Then, always try to minimize them as much as you can.

Therefore, the best approach is, like you mention, concatenate strings first, and then use the resulting string.

Answer (score 0):

You should add your `li`s to your `ul` before inserting into the DOM:

```
var $ul = $('<ul>');

$ul.append('<li>...</li>');
$ul.append('<li>...</li>');
/* .................... */

$ul.appendTo(myDiv);
```

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
var ul = '<ul>';
ul += '<li>first</li>';
ul += '<li>second</li>';
ul += '</ul>';
myDiv.append(ul);
```